# Configuring Second URL for Reporting Services to Respond on port 443

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, ssrs, microsoft

We have a web server hosting several websites.

DNS is configured to point ..com to the web server. One of the sites acts a proxy and redirects https requests
to a seperate SSRS server. We have a wildcard ssl certficate for *..com.

Recently the certificate expired and needed to be renewed. Since that happend the new certificate has been installed on the webserver. On the
 SSRS server the service url and management url have been configured so that the bindings now use the renewed certificate.

When requests are sent to the URL https://..com/Reports and https://..com/ReportServer then it works fine.

One of our users wants to be able to access the URL by the server name so they would be entering https:///ReportServer into the address bar.
When they go via this address, they get a certificate error. I have tried creating a self signed certificate and binding that to 443 on the management URL using
the SSRS management console. This didn't work and when they go to this URL they still get a certificate error. It appears to still be trying the
certificate for *..com.

Can anyone advise on how I can go about getting it to respond on 443 to both the URLS below?

```
https://<reporting>.<ourdomain>.com/ReportServer
https://<servername>/ReportServer
```

Comment: To see which certificate is used for incoming HTTPS requests, you need to dig further into HTTP API, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Comment: If the URL is going direct to the server name then would it still be using IIS on the webserver? Isn't https://<servername>/ReportServer directing straight to the server hosting SSRS?

Comment: Keep in mind that IIS (or other HTTP related products, SSRS) does not handle HTTPS/TLS itself, but delegates to Windows/HTTP API. So whatever HTTPS URLs are handled by those mappings and you need to make sure you have the right ones.